# Root - How to remove one of the superuser app?

Tags: root-access, superuser

I rooted my phone a month ago and downloaded the SuperUser app yesterday.

However, when I use the app SuperSU, it is not running and it said i need to update a file. I could not update it.

What can I do? How can I remove SuperUser?

Comment: SuperSU has an option to remove / change to another Super User app. Does SuperUser have this? If not your best bet is to remove both and flash the latest SuperSU from chainfire directly in your recovery, this should remove the binaries issue. Both really do have the same functionality though, so if SuperUser is working for you, it might be worth just removing SuperSU instead.

Comment: And you shouldn't run both at the same time, just to make clear: Decide whether to use SuperSU ***or*** SuperUser. It's like Highlander: There only can be one. Remove the other.

Comment: @Izzy I wish I could vote up that comment a million times.

Comment: @dotVezz I could make it an answer, to give you the chance of awarding it a bounty #D

Comment: @Izzy brilliant comment there ^^^^ :D

Comment: If you have root access, just delete it from /system/app or /system/priv-app

Answer (score 4):

1. Run the SuperSU app. If you’ve uninstalled it for whichever reason, all you need to do is Reinstall it from the Google Play Store.
2. Click on the Settings tab on the top right corner, and then click Full Unroot. Confirm with 'Continue'.
3. Once this operation is done, which takes a few minutes, you can reboot your Android.
4. Uninstall SuperSU.( If Exists.....)

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a custom recovery (ClockworkMod or TWRP) installed then you should be able to flash the [Superuser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.superuser) recovery zip which will remove any other binaries/files related to other superuser apps in the process.

The SuperSu app may still be installed but you can un-install that yourself as you would any other app.

Quote from Superuser play store description:

> Manual installation with the recovery zip:
>
> Recommended if you are having installation issues or are not rooted
>   http://download.clockworkmod.com/superuser/superuser.zip

Comment: will this wipe my phone data?

Comment: It shouldn't, it will just remove any remnants of any previous superuser (or SuperSU) install and then copy the files it requires. As RossC mentioned, there is probably a similar zip file for SuperSu if you want to keep that app instead.

Comment: Android 4.4. SuperSU is still here, but SuperUser is running normally. Thanks.

Comment: It might not remove the SuperSu app itself. You should be able to uninstall/remove that manually.

Comment: Can I remove SuperSU?

Comment: @Jamie yes, see my updated answer.

Comment: HELP!!!!!!!!!!! My superuser app disappeared! However my phone is still rooted. How can I get back my superuser?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/12816/discussion-between-bmdixon-and-jamie)

Comment: Sorry! I have only 1 reputation.

Comment: I tried to install superuser via google play store again, but it was painful.

Comment: I can only flash the zip again.

Comment: Try flashing the zip again, that will restore the Superuser app. You could try removing the SuperSu app before flashing to see if that makes any difference.

Comment: actually, how to get more reputation?

Comment: @Jamie, you probably want to read our [help] about reputation and how the site works.

Comment: Flash a super user app in recovery. You will need to do this first time usually anyway. It'll take 2 minutes! You won't lose data. Reputation is earned by asking upvoted questions, giving upvoted answers, and accepting answers that are useful to you. The more you partake, the higher it goes!

Comment: When i flash the first time, i only take 5 seconds lol

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed them as system apps, use any root browser and delete apks from /system/apps, else, delete them from /data/app and then install anything you like from Play Store. Do NOT flash zip or Google Play updates and any apk of that app will not install.

P.S. SuperSU has uninstall option.

Answer (score 0):

Download 360 Security. Make sure that you are accepting the Permission (Don't Deny it). Open 360 Security--> Apps Uninstall--> select System Apps--> select Super User--> click on Uninstall.

Answer (score 0):

Update supersu 
ignore binary installation if prompted 
go to settings select "clean up for other supersu app (wait for it to uninstall)
Reboot device and voila I just tried that not 10 minutes ago. I've had that problem for some time and that finally got rid of it not a trace of it on my phone

Answer (score 0):

Download Kingroot. If it works on your phone. Then just root the phone using Kingroot. Once in Kingroot, click more options, Uninstall tool, built-in, select "supersu", and simply delete it. Voila, it's gone.

Answer (score -1):

**How to fix the SuperSU binary file issue (at leat on the MXIII-G player)**

Install a terminal app from the playstore and connect so you get the prompt.

Become root and check how the /system partition is mounted as read-only (ro), In particular note the device

```
$ su
# mount | grep system
/dev/block/system /system ext4 ro,relatime,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
```

Remount the partiton in read-write mode (rw)

```
# mount -o rw,remount /dev/block/system /system
```

Finally check if it was mounted in read-write mode (rw)

```
# mount | grep system
/dev/block/system /system ext4 rw,relatime,barrier=1,data=ordered 0 0
```

Update the SuperSU via the Play Store and reboot when done.

Comment: I don't understand this. All you've done here is remount system partition in rw mode and then recommended update of the app. How does remounting the system partition helps? SuperSU doesn't require writing into system partition just to update itself. It is an app, like any other app and the update can be stored in data partition yet the app can remain a system app. Please provide an evidence to support your claim.